# Changing an XPath query from a value within for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to do a for each on each page:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/page">
   <xsl:value-of select="/root/titles/@page/"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Sample XML;

```
<root>
  <titles>
   <en>A title</en>
   <de>Ein Titel</de> 
 </titles>
 <page title="de">
    ....
 </page>
</root>
```

The problem I am having is that the XPath isn't resolving to the `/root/titles/de/...`
How can I get it to work?

Comment: I realize the question is quite specific, however I'm not able to come up with the right words to google it.

Comment: I don't think that any of the answers provided are correct. See mine if it fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/root/page">
   <xsl:variable name="language" select="@title"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="/root/titles/*[name()=$language]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

now it works for me!

Comment: I cannot try at the moment but I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error loading stylesheet: XPath parse failure: Name or Nodetype test expected:

Comment: The result of the value-of comes back blank for me but the path prints out. EDIT: Nevermind... its a completely unrelated issue

Comment: ah ok! I was investigating further! np ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you want, but it looks like you should be aware that `xsl:for-each` changes the context to the selected node, just like a template does.  So this might get you somewhere:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/page">
   <xsl:value-of select="/root/titles/*[name()=current()/@title]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm wanting the XSL to grab /root/title/de because de was an attribute within <page>..</page>

Comment: @monksy, sorry, misread, updated my answer.  Basically like danyolgiax's only without the extra variable.  You can also use `local-name`, but it's only needed if you're dealing with namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xsl:key`. Because is not clear the output you need I've provided just an example for you showing how to get the `title` from `titles` for each `page` according to the page language.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested under **Saxon 6.5.5**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="titles" match="titles/*" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
     <xsl:for-each select="page">
             <xsl:value-of select="concat('title-',@title,key('titles',@title),'&#xA;')"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on this input

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <titles>
   <en>A title</en>
   <de>Ein Titel</de> 
 </titles>
 <page title="de">
    ....
    </page>
     <page title="en">
    ....
 </page>
</root>
```

produces:

```
title-de:Ein Titel
title-en:A title
```

---

Tested on Mozilla Firefox 3.6.17 as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test_trans.xsl"?>
<root>
  <titles>
   <en>A title</en>
   <de>Ein Titel</de> 
 </titles>
 <page title="de">
    ....
    </page>
     <page title="en">
    ....
 </page>
</root>
```

Produces

```
 title-deEin Titeltitle-enA title
```

Obviously without new lines, because we are displaying it in a browser and the transform should be changed to produce HTML.

Comment: What about for Firefox? I'm getting a "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed. " only on the key.

Comment: Tried on Mozilla Firefox 3.6.17 and works fine as expected. See my answer edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/page">
    <xsl:variable name="language" select="@title"\>
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/titles/$language"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I updated the code... I just thought I'd give you fair warning